# Request module node.js: How add query to GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, youtube-api

SO I started using the node.js request module to make request to the youtube api.
I could make the query string of the below link myself, but I'm pretty sure there is a shortcut. Does anyone know it?

**The youtube API link**

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=black%20panther&key=AIzaSyD4shfocwn-Ed3Feuoo9fG3d2K2GjHmKeI&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&type=video'
```

**So, I'm looking for a shortcut to add the above query string to my http request**

```
request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', function (error, response, body) {

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `querystring` in node js just pass a json object with query parameters and it will convert it to query string

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const obj = { part: 'snippet', q: 'black' };
const urlQueryString = querystring.stringify(obj);

request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?' + urlQueryString , 
function (error, response, body) {

});
```